# Sublime Text custom autocomplete hierarchy

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, hierarchy

Im using a **.sublime-completions** file to write my custom autocomplete code:

```
{
    "scope": "source.python",

    "completions":
    [
        "logic",
        "True",
        "False",
        "Object"
    ]
}
```

But I'm missing a way of creating a **hierarchy**, like this:

```
{
    "scope": "source.python",

    "completions":
    [
        "logic",
        "True",
        "False",

        "Object":
        [
            "worldPosition",
            "applyForce",
            "name",
            "delete"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Does this feature exists? Is there a way to create it?